# How to enable / troubleshoot split view?

Tags: fullscreen, macos

I have just installed El Capitan on my MacBook Pro 13 mid 2012

I can't get split view to work either via the mission control method or the green button one.

Does anybody know this is supposed to work?

Comment: If you don't get good answers, consider explaining what precisely you are doing for both "methods" - it would be best to link to an Apple support article or upload a screen shot showing your efforts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was driving me crazy as well. Go to System Preferences -> Mission Control and make sure that ‘Displays have separate Spaces’ is checked. You’ll have to log out and log back in for the change to take affect. That fixed it for me.

Comment: man!!!!! I love you!!

Comment: I don't how this was unchecked on my machine! But your answer really saved the day. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

- Open Safari.app
- Open two windows in safari (not two tabs in one window)
- Press and hold the maximize button (it's green by default, but also can be grey if you choose so)
- After half a second or more, drag that window to the left or the right of the screen. One half of the screen should be overlaid with the hilight color to indicate where it will land when you drop it

This split screen feature isn't called out as needing specific hardware, so you should be good to go. http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/

If your user account isn't working, make a new test user in the Accounts preference pane and log out of your old user. Retest in the new user account to make sure you don't just have some settings file corruption or issue.

Comment: man, I swear, nothing happen. Neither if I open a full screen safari, and try to drag another one on the mission control preview

Answer (score 0):

It seems to only work on some apps. I have been trying to get two emails to open in split screen so that I can make edits to one, and I cannot get it to work. I have been able to get Chrome and Messages into split screen, and haven't tested much else.